# Unable to patch user DirectoryObjectUnauthorizedAccessException http 500

Tags: python, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, adal

I am trying to patch users in our Azure active directory to update the hireDate. (Python sample below)

```
message = {'hireDate': hire_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")}
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
response = sess.patch(f'{graph_url}/users/{user_id}', json=message, headers=headers)
```

Where session has the correct token obtained using the adal library.

I have tried as both application and delegated permissions (i am a tenant admin as well). With User.ReadWrte.all and Directory.Readwrite.All.

I get and HTTP 500 repsonse with error:

```
 {'code': '-1, Microsoft.Office.Server.Directory.DirectoryObjectUnauthorizedAccessException', 'message': 'Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.', 'innerError': {'request-id': 'xxxx', 'date': '2019-09-11T09:47:38'}}
```

I can do the same request for my own userId and it works. I can also read all profiles using the same authentication. Also a similar request using the graph explorer works for any user.

Any ideas how i can update all users in my tenant?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a issue with formatting of the date.

As per the documentation

**"The Timestamp type represents date and time information using ISO 8601 format and is always in UTC time. For example, midnight UTC on Jan 1, 2014 would look like this: '2014-01-01T00:00:00Z'"**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request-body

Could you please try updating the date and see if it works.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I believe that is the correct formatting already, here is an example of a rendered body `{"hireDate": "2012-04-19T00:00:00Z"}`. Also the same body using the graph explorer works.

Comment: Also the exact same request works if I update my profile using delegated credentials its  when i update other users profiles it fails even though i think i have the correct permissions.

Comment: Can you add your details in this issue  : https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/296